# Record a visitor session in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've been tasked with creating an e-learning system. The client want the users session recording when they are within certain parts of the application, enabling Tutors to confirm that they have interacted with the page in manor consistent with learning.

However I'm unable to find a valid solution anywhere.

My plan was to develop an ASP.NET Core MVC application which triggered the screen recording on certain pages, saving the recording with a reference between it and the course they are viewing.

I know its possible as there are a number of screen recording solutions for tracking visitors available. I myself use one that allows a live/recorded view of the user with all the associated click/move/tap feedback, and this is achieved by injecting Javascript into the front end web site, without the need for any additional components on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

@Powerman2015, you can capture that information when you display the view I.E

```
public ActionResult Page1()
{
  Session["page1"] = true;
  return View();
}
```

If you need them to interact with elements of that page, then you can submit the values passing to a controller and assign it there.

This is on razor view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyActionResult", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
```

This is your controller

```
public ActionResult MyActionResult()    
{
  Session["page1"] = true;
  Your code...
}
```